# \AddEverypageHook at end of page

Tags: page-breaking

`\AddEverypageHook` works at the start of a page. How can I add a hook to the every last part of a page right before a pagebreak?

Essentially I want to watermark the pages BUT I want to do it after the page contents have been created but immediately before the pagebreak. The "watermark"(not a watermark but just similar concept) will depend on macro values set(like `\thepage`) so it can't happen at the very end of the document.

Comment: Perhaps the [turnthepage](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/turnthepage) will be of interest.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked out Martin Schroder's [everyshi](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/everyshi) package? Quoting from the introductory section of the package's user guide:

> This package provides the hooks `\EveryShipout` and `\AtNextShipout`
>   whose arguments are executed after the output routine has constructed
>   `\box255`, and before `\shipout` is called.
>
> An example application for this package would be a package for adding
>   text to the bottom of each page. Such a package does exist: `prelim2e`.
>
> Another application is a package for adding pictures to every page: `esopic`.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a footer to specify this content, which makes [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). The following [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/5764) defines a page style `mystyle` that sets some text `/stuff` just outside the text block beyond the last line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
  \fancyfoot[R]{\smash{\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\raisebox{\footskip}{\rlap{\hspace{2em}%
    /stuff
  }}}}}%
}
\AtEndDocument{\thispagestyle{plain}}% Last page should be plain
\pagestyle{plain}% Plain page style throughout
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\pagestyle{mystyle}% Switch to mystyle page style
\lipsum[16-30]
\end{document}
```

`mystyle` is activated using `\pagestyle{mystyle}` and deactivated using a different page style. To remove `mystyle` from the last page, use a different page style `\AtEndDocument`.

If there's no unprocessed floats at the end of the document, this should be sufficient. Otherwise, one could use something like [`pageslts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pageslts) to access the "very last page." Additionally, the footer can be made conditional to only display content in certain locations.

The actual footer is set in a `r`ight-aligned `\linewidth`-width box, raised by `\footskip` to elevate it above the regular footer. Additionally, it's shifted `2em` to the right, and then set with a `r`ight over`lap` to left-align it in the margin.